# Firefox restarting problem

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser, reboot

I'm using Firefox 3.0.13 in Ubuntu 8.10 and I have a problem that it suddenly disables the `back, forward, refresh, stop` options. After updating Firefox using following commands

sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install firefox

it always asks me to restart the browser due to a new version being found. How do I fix it? How do I reinstall properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove firefox; sudo apt-get install firefox` will remove the existing version and re-install - but it will leave configuration files intact.

`sudo apt-get purge firefox; sudo apt-get install firefox` will purge the existing version (ie, remove the binaries *and* the configuration files - but I'm not sure it will clean up your ~/.firefox, you may have to remove that by hand) and then re-install.

If all you want to do is force a fresh install, `sudo apt-get reinstall firefox` will do that for you.